# Can you search for posts / news / links, etc... a user likes in facebook using Koala gem for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm testing out the Koala gem for rails and facebook api. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way of searching and displaying all of 'a' user's liked posts, news, links, etc.. using Koala gem.

Anyone know where to possibly start? I was thinking `@graph.search('me', 'likes')` ??

Comment: I guess I should be more specific @graph.get_connections('me', 'likes') for example returns pages I've liked... however I'm looking to find everything else, like pages, news, stories, links, etc.. a user liked in the past.

Comment: Anyone know if there's a way to access the Facebook Activity Log of a user using Koala gem?